# Heroku toolbelt not being recognized OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, command-line

I've tried to install and reinstall the Heroku toolbelt about 10 times now but I cannot seem to figure out how to get it installed properly.  I've tried deleting and adding ssh keys multiple times as well as many other stackoverflow solutions but don't know where to go from here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm stuck due to my very basic understanding of the command line.

```
$ heroku # or heroku login, heroku help, etc.
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

$ which heroku
/usr/bin/heroku
```

This is the contents of that file

```
#!/usr/local/heroku/ruby/bin/ruby
# encoding: UTF-8

# resolve bin path, ignoring symlinks
require "pathname"
bin_file = Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath

# add locally vendored gems to libpath
gem_dir = File.expand_path("../../vendor/gems", bin_file)
Dir["#{gem_dir}/**/lib"].each do |libdir|
  $:.unshift libdir
end

# add self to libpath
$:.unshift File.expand_path("../../lib", bin_file)

# inject any code in ~/.heroku/client over top
require "heroku/updater"
Heroku::Updater.inject_libpath

# start up the CLI
require "heroku/cli"
Heroku.user_agent = "heroku-toolbelt/#{Heroku::VERSION} (#{RUBY_PLATFORM}) ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}"
Heroku::CLI.start(*ARGV)
```

bashrc
    export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

Comment: if you are on mac osx, why not just use their installer?https://toolbelt.heroku.com/ does everything for you?

Comment: Thats exactly what I used and it hasn't worked on my new computer (macbook air mavericks) for some reason I cannot figure out. Setup was very simple on my last one.

Comment: Your first 3 lines indicate that typing "heroku" appears to try to open some git repo, do you have some alias thats getting in the way?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I had an alias "push heroku" and removing that seems to be working. Thanks a lot!! You have no idea how frustrated I've been on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias of "push heroku" was preventing the toolbelt from being called.  Removing this enabled the heroku commands to work properly and proper setup was then possible.